# Can't add products to shopping cart / cart keeps loading Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, addtocart, shopping-cart, magento2.2.4

I recently copied a **website** over to **another host** by using the **import tool**.

After this I don't seem able to add **items** into my **shopping cart**.

The button keeps saying **loading** and the Ajax loader shows near the shopping cart Icon. I checked the ajax call and it shows this as **responsetext**:

```
array(0) {↵}↵
```

With a statusText **"parse error"**.

I am using a fairly unmodified **magento ver. 2.2.4**. And the shopping cart is working correctly on the original site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a conflicting module!

So kids, if you ever encounter A problem like described above just remove some newly added modules and check again.